# How do I get all the Compile Time Errors at once in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to compile a java file and get all the errors to the list. So far I am using java's built in compiler API, but it has some problems.

For example,

```java
//demo.java
class demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array = new int[10]
    }
}
```

we can see that there is semicolon missing and [] (array brackets) are missing.
But Java Compiler API will only return

```java
demo.java:4: error: ';' expected
        int array = new int[10]
                               ^
1 error
```

But It should say there is missing `[]` brackets and semicolon `;`

Is there any other way to compile java file and return all the errors?

If there is any way to do it using Java Compiler API then let me know.

If there are any  other external Libraries or tool that compile a java file and return the error status.
External Library should:

- If the file has no errors then the library should say that file has no errors.
- If the Java file has some errors then library should return list of errors with their line number and error message.

I searched a lot about this web. But Only found the one solution i.e. Java compiler API. But I want to try some other tools too.

Answer (score 4):

The Java compiler does not warn you about a "missing `[]`" because that is not a possible error that the Java compiler can ever emit; if you fix the missing semicolon (which is a syntax error) in this code, then the error reported is:

```
incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
```

which makes sense as an error, because the variable's type is declared as `int` but the initializer's expression is of type `int[]`.

By describing the error as "missing `[]`", you make it sound like another syntax error, but actually an "incompatible types" error is not a syntax error; it occurs during the [type-checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Type_checking) stage, which occurs after [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). However, if there are any syntax errors at the parsing stage then the compiler doesn't enter the type-checking stage because there is no valid parse tree to type-check.

So the Java compiler will not report both a syntax error and a type error in the same compilation unit, regardless of whether you use the command-line `javac` tool or the compiler API.

Comment: But can this be done using any external tool or any library thats what I’m asking  ?

Comment: The Java compiler API should return the same errors that the `javac` command-line tool returns, which is up to the first 100 errors by default. If you have tried it with a source code file which the `javac` command-line tool reports multiple errors and the API only reports the first one, then post the source code. Otherwise what you are asking for is logically impossible; the Java Language Specification defines what is or is not an error, so if any other tool reports different errors than `javac` then either that tool or `javac` is not a conforming implementation of Java.

Comment: @kaya3 that’s not the way it works. The specification defines what is a *correct* program. So all compilers should agree about what is a correct program and in turn, what is not correct, but when it comes to reporting the error, they enter the field of interpreting (guessing) what mistake the author did. This reporting can differ significantly and in my opinion, all current compiler fail badly in this area. One reason is that they are truly trying what the OP wants, to report additional errors when the context is unreliable due to previous errors.

Comment: I just checked this: ecj (the backend compiler of Eclipse) does report a missing semicolon and a type mismatch at the same time, but also a third error, “insert ArrayInitializer to complete Expression”, which demonstrates the problem: we know that the code is not matching the official grammar, but we don’t know what is missing, as that means guessing the programmers intention. In the past, compilers used to say “`}` unexpected” at this code location, which wasn’t helpful either.

Comment: @Holger The JLS contains the phrase *"It is a compile-time error ..."* repeatedly when describing conditions on which errors should occur, so it is quite correct to say that the JLS defines what is an error, not just what is correct.

Comment: @kaya3 there are statements like “it’s a compile-time error if X verb Y”, but it still doesn’t say that the compiler’s error message has to be literally like this. In some cases, it is, but in a lot of cases, the error message still reads different. All that the formal statement implies, is that “X verb Y” is not allowed to get compiled without an error. And in case of *syntax errors*, you won’t find such statements in the specification. There’s just a formal grammar. As said, this question’s specific example already allows at least two (I see at least three) different error messages.

Comment: @Holger I didn't say the JLS restricts how errors are reported, only that it defines what is or is not an error. Reporting an error defined by the JLS in different words than the JLS uses would be conforming, but reporting an error that the JLS doesn't say is an error would not be conforming.

Comment: The starting point was that the OP wishes a compiler to tell both, the missing semicolon and the type mismatch and, as said, Eclipse’s compiler does this. Plus another error. So your claim that all compilers report the same errors is just wrong. And that’s all within the specification. As all, the specification mandates, is that this incorrect program does not get compiled but produces at least one error message. It would be entirely legal if a compiler only said “*there is at least one error that must be fixed*” on every kind of error, without any additional details. Details are not mandatory

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. The Java compiler stops processing a source file when it hits an error. The C/C++ compiler does what you want but most following error messages are misleading and not useful.

To get a list of all errors, the compiler would need to use AI technologies. The compiler would need to guess what you meant.

Comment: Is there any way using compiler parser or language processing tools ?

Comment: This is false; the Java compiler does not stop processing on the first error. Try compiling `class A { a; b; }` and you will get two syntax errors, not one.

Comment: Yes @kaya3 is right ! Compiler doesn’t stop when it found any error

Comment: Nevertheless, compilation notionally occurs in 'stages',  A sufficiently severe error in one stage can make it meaningless to run the next stage, and therefore it is impossible to report errors that would be found by that next stage.